Kindle Unlimited book where people use rocks to gain powers
I'm trying to remember a Kindle Unlimited book where people use rocks to gain powers. The only things I remember about the book are that the male protagonist's village is a granite mine, and that the different characters would use certain rocks to get powers, like granite makes you strong and hard, opal gives control of water, marble gives fire powers, and basalt gives speed.
That's all I remember.

This is Set in Stone: A Progression Fantasy by Frank Morin.
The protagonist lives near a granite quarry.

Connor stopped on his favorite vantage rock and rested, hands on
knees, breathing hard. He'd jogged back up the pass from the north
peak where he'd left the torc, covering the distance in a
ground-eating lope. The noonday sun shone warm on his face as he stood
and scanned the valley.
He loved the spot. To his right reared the majestic peak of Wick Tor,
its high summit flanked by clouds, with the huge open pit of the
quarry cut into its flanks about half a mile from where Connor rested.
The pounding of hammers and chisels reached him dimly. The tempo was
fast, constant, as everyone worked hard to finish early.

Marble tastes 'spicy' and gives you fire powers.

He sucked on the rock, but didn't need to bother. He'd always liked
marble, more than ever since tasting the oven. "Spice."
He'd been practicing so much with marble in the past two days that he
instinctively pried open the stone's power and released a tiny jet of
flame. Then he yelped and spit the rock out as it started burning his
tongue.

Basalt gives you super-speed.

"I'm surprised they gave you basalt in the middle of a battle if you'd
never really tried it before."
So it was basalt that fueled the Striders' super speed.

The e-book was a Kindle Unlimited exclusive when it was released.
